# Docker ps not showing health status of container

Tags: docker

After `docker ps` why is no health status provided (like `healthy` or `unhealthy`) of my first container as shown in the screenshot below?
[image]

Comment: I see status column too with docker ps.  Dont we have different version of docker? 
My version of docker is "Docker version 25.0.0". What is yours?

Comment: Do any of your Dockerfiles have a healthcheck ? https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#healthcheck

Comment: They are all written in one docker-compose file and the second and third container already have a healthcheck, whereas the first one does not, which is my task now to change this until I stumbled upon the missing health status...

Comment: Check the path to the Dockerfile of first one, and then add `HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:3000 || exit 1 ` or similiar depends on your code

Comment: Oh wow its that simple! Thats the answer to the question! I simply overread that the last container also has a healthcheck since the container name differs to the service name in the compose file. After adding a healthcheck to the first container a status is shown as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose, check the path to the Dockerfile of first one, and then add

```
 HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=3s \   
 CMD curl -f http://localhost:3000 || exit 1
```

More info:
https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#healthcheck

Another option is to add a healthcheck in your docker-compose file, like:

```yaml
healthcheck:
      test: curl -f "http:localhost:8000/hello/" || exit 1
      interval: 60s   # check every minute
      timeout: 20s    # maximum time to wait for a response
      retries: 3      # number of retries before considering the container unhealthy
      start_period: 2m
```

This results to a status providing the health status of a container.